# Problemas com responsividade no bootstrap para telas sm e xs

Tags: css3, bootstrap-4, layout-responsivo

Amigos devs, minha tela não fica responsiva para dispositivos pequenos e extra pequenos (sm e xs), aparece uma barra lateral branca do lado direto da tela e que a medida em que a tela diminui mais, maior ela fica (a barra), tomando até metade da tela em dispositivos muito pequenos. Segue o código, desculpe se não fiz corretamente, primeira pergunta publicada.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
    <title>Efeito Parallax</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale = 1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">


    <!-- Icones -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Fontes -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

     <!-- Galeria de fotos -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/baguettebox.js/1.8.1/baguetteBox.min.css">


    <style type="text/css">


        .header-site{
            background-image: url(img/a.jpg);
            background-position: center top;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            color: #ffffff;
            padding-top: 300px;
            padding-bottom: 300px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .content-site{
            padding-top: 200px;
            padding-bottom: 200px;

        }

        .img-site {
            background-image: url(img/a.jpg);
            background-position: center top;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            padding-top: 200px;
            padding-bottom: 200px;

        }

     </style>
    </head>
    <body>


    <!-- MENU - NAV - HEADER -->

     <section class="header-site">
     <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <h1 class="text-center">BEM-VINDO</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus, rerum sed necessitatibus architecto velit ipsum, iste, natus aut omnis pariatur fugit. Quam facilis illo minima corporis dolorum in qui quidem. 
 </p>
                <p class="lead text-center">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Encomende</a>
                    </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </section>


    <section class="content-site">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h1 class="text-center">Fusce campe titulo ahahaha </h1>
                <p class="text-center"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta alias, quas optio sed repellat, aperiam deleniti hic error fugit aliquid tenetur reprehenderit et dolor dolores, iusto repellendus officia? Odit, officiis.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="img-thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPjIi.jpg">
                    <div class="caption text-center"></div>
                    <h3>supendise  Amaoroso</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus reiciendis iste, aut laborum, id veritatis minus rerum fugiat cumque autem optio amet? Omnis provident aperiam aliquam reiciendis at, eligendi odio.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="img-thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/340x250">
                    <div class="caption text-center"></div>
                    <h3>supendise  Amaoroso 2</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus reiciendis iste, aut laborum, id veritatis minus rerum fugiat cumque autem optio amet? Omnis provident aperiam aliquam reiciendis at, eligendi odio.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="img-thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/340x250">
                    <div class="caption text-center"></div>
                    <h3>supendise  Amaoroso 3</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus reiciendis iste, aut laborum, id veritatis minus rerum fugiat cumque autem optio amet? Omnis provident aperiam aliquam reiciendis at, eligendi odio.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     </section>

     <section class="img-site">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h1 class="text-center">CONTRATE AGORA</h1>
                <p class="lead text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus, rerum sed necessitatibus architecto velit ipsum, iste, natus aut omnis pariatur fugit. Quam facilis illo minima corporis dolorum in qui quidem.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     </section>

    <section class="footer-site">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sx-12">
                <p class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime dignissimos labore quod! Ducimus vero illum magnam laborum nesciunt molestias provident, aut veritatis nostrum cum deserunt, voluptatibus, pariatur culpa voluptate suscipit.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     </section>

     <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
     <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
     <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

[image: Essa é a área do hmtl em azul, deixando uma barra branca do lado.]

Answer (score 0):

Se problema aparentemente é pq vc não definiu uma largura para as imagens que está usando.

Adicione nas tags das imagens `class="w-100"` isso vai limita-las a 100% da largura do `container`. Aqui pelo menos aparentemente funcionou.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Galeria de fotos -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/baguettebox.js/1.8.1/baguetteBox.min.css">


<style type="text/css">
    .header-site {
        background-image: url(img/a.jpg);
        background-position: center top;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        color: #ffffff;
        padding-top: 300px;
        padding-bottom: 300px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .content-site {
        padding-top: 200px;
        padding-bottom: 200px;

    }

    .img-site {
        background-image: url(img/a.jpg);
        background-position: center top;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        padding-top: 200px;
        padding-bottom: 200px;

    }

    .img-thumbnail img {}

</style>
</head>

<body>


    <!-- MENU - NAV - HEADER -->

    <section class="header-site">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <h1 class="text-center">BEM-VINDO</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus, rerum sed necessitatibus architecto velit ipsum, iste, natus aut omnis pariatur fugit. Quam facilis illo minima corporis dolorum in qui quidem.
                    </p>
                    <p class="lead text-center">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Encomende</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>


    <section class="content-site">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <h1 class="text-center">Fusce campe titulo ahahaha </h1>
                    <p class="text-center"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta alias, quas optio sed repellat, aperiam deleniti hic error fugit aliquid tenetur reprehenderit et dolor dolores, iusto repellendus officia? Odit, officiis.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="img-thumbnail">
                        <img class="w-100" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPjIi.jpg">
                        <div class="caption text-center"></div>
                        <h3>supendise Amaoroso</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus reiciendis iste, aut laborum, id veritatis minus rerum fugiat cumque autem optio amet? Omnis provident aperiam aliquam reiciendis at, eligendi odio.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="img-thumbnail">
                        <img class="w-100" src="http://placehold.it/340x250">
                        <div class="caption text-center"></div>
                        <h3>supendise Amaoroso 2</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus reiciendis iste, aut laborum, id veritatis minus rerum fugiat cumque autem optio amet? Omnis provident aperiam aliquam reiciendis at, eligendi odio.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="img-thumbnail">
                        <img class="w-100" src="http://placehold.it/340x250">
                        <div class="caption text-center"></div>
                        <h3>supendise Amaoroso 3</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus reiciendis iste, aut laborum, id veritatis minus rerum fugiat cumque autem optio amet? Omnis provident aperiam aliquam reiciendis at, eligendi odio.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="img-site">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <h1 class="text-center">CONTRATE AGORA</h1>
                    <p class="lead text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus, rerum sed necessitatibus architecto velit ipsum, iste, natus aut omnis pariatur fugit. Quam facilis illo minima corporis dolorum in qui quidem.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="footer-site">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sx-12">
                    <p class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime dignissimos labore quod! Ducimus vero illum magnam laborum nesciunt molestias provident, aut veritatis nostrum cum deserunt, voluptatibus, pariatur culpa voluptate suscipit.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oi Hugo, cara genial, resolve o problema dos cards. Mas confesso que não era este o problema maior e sim a imagem de fundo da tela inicial. Talvez não apareça bem na imagem, mas é um efeito parallax, poderia ser só imagem de fundo fixa também, porém quando diminuo a tela aparece uma barra branca apenas do lado direito e vai tomando proporções maiores.

Comment: @LucasMendesRibeiro cara aqui eu não consegui simular esse seu problema, mesmo em telas bem estreitas isso não acontece. Vc tem esse código publicado em algum lugar onde de para ver esse problema? Olha aqui nesse Codepen que não vai ter esse problema acontecendo https://codepen.io/hugocsl/pen/oNvavBN olha ai

Comment: Realmente @hugocsl não aparece neste editor. Estranho aparecer conorme a imagem que eu printei, porém vou subir no servidor e ver como fica no meu celular. Agradeço tua ajuda amigo!

Comment: @LucasMendesRibeiro legal jovem, qq dúvida estou na área, se vc achar que te ajudou de alguma forma um  up é bem vindo